# I can't compile boost - can't find *.o file

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile Boost libraries.
I'm typing

```
bootstrap.bat gcc
```

which completes succesfully, then

```
b2 install --prefix=c:/Tools/boost toolset=gcc variant=release
```

And I receive bunch of errors:

```
"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pedantic -mthreads -Wno-variadic-macros -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1,<python>2.7,<target-os>windows:<python.interpreter>C:\Python27\python -DBOOST_CHRONO_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_TIMER_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-mingw-4.9.2\release\link-static\threading-multi\unit_test_parameters.o" "libs\test\src\unit_test_parameters.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-mingw-4.9.2\release\link-static\threading-multi\unit_test_parameters.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-mingw-4.9.2\release\link-static\threading-multi\xml_log_formatter.o
File can't be found.
```

about like every file and nothing gets compiled.
Shouldn't o files be created while building? What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the prefix parameter to the bootstrap call, not the b2 invocation? Typically, that is information already needed when setting up the build environment (which is what bootstrap does).

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's a bug. You should not need the prefix param during the bootstrap. Glad it solved your problem though.

Comment: Looked it up. You CAN set up the output directory for b2. The parameter in this case, however, is [build-dir](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html). prefix is the corresponding [bootstrap option](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).